# how to use a column alias when selecting * from a table inner joined with another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, alias

I am using MS Access 2010.  I have inner joined two tables (2 columns from one table, and all columns from the other) and would like to use an alias on one of the columns from the table that I select all the columns.  Here as an example of the current SQL

```
SELECT 
    Cars.brand, Cars.owner, * 
FROM 
    Cars INNER JOIN Inspections ON Cars.vin = Inspections.vin
```

Right now when I run this, the vin column is returned as 'Inspections.vin'.  I would like it to just read 'vin'.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can't specify aliases for the columns in `*`. You can't have your cake and eat it.

Comment: You have to select all required columns from the second table also then only you can define alias for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add table name, currently you select all columns from both tables:

```
SELECT 
    Cars.brand, Cars.owner, Inspections.* 
FROM 
    Cars INNER JOIN Inspections ON Cars.vin = Inspections.vin
```

Comment: Edited the answer, didn't catch the question correctly before

Comment: Ah!  I didn't even realize I was pulling all columns from both tables.  This answer was the ticket, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign an alias to columns that are explicitly included in your `select` statement. Otherwise, all those within the `all` part of your query will return its original column name

```
SELECT 
    Cars.brand, Cars.owner, [vin] = Cars.vin, * 
FROM 
    Cars INNER JOIN Inspections ON Cars.vin = Inspections.vin
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for since you want all the columns from Inspections.  You can't use `*` if you want aliases; instead you will need to specify every column you want from Inspections.  In my example it's as if Inspections has only two variables; just add more `Inpections.whatever` until you have all the columns.

```
SELECT Car.brand, Cars.owner, Inspections.vin as vin, Inspections.othervar
    FROM Cars
INNER JOIN Inspections 
    ON Cars.vin = Inspections.vin
```